# GMail API Not authenticating properly

Tags: oauth, gmail-api, google-authentication

I'm following the [Google .Net Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet). I've correctly (I believe) set up the app in the Developers console and have got this in an MVC controller...

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    static string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly };
    static string ApplicationName = "APP NAME";
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

        Run();

        return View();
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        UserCredential credential;
        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = "<<MY REAL CLIENT ID IS HERE>>",
                ClientSecret = "<<MY REAL CLIENT SECRET IS HERE>>"
            },
            Scopes,
            "<<MY EMAIL ADDRESS>>",
            CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("Mail.Labels")).Result;

    }
}
```

I have set the project up to run on port 37623 every time and I have set up the client on the developer console to allow a redirect to `http://localhost:37623/Home/Index`.

When I run the app I'm offerent a list of GMail accounts (I have a couple) even though I have explicitly stated which account I want to use. When I click account selector to pick an account, I'm immediately shown an error page saying I have been returned a 400 Error: redirect_uri_mismatch.

If I look at the request details on the error page it shows this...

```
access_type=offline
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly
response_type=code
redirect_uri=http://localhost:41509/authorize/
client_id=<<MY CLIENT ID>>
```

As you can see, the redirect_uri **is** wrong; it's pointing to port 41509 (in this instance; it changes with each call).

What am I missing? What is it that I should be doing that I'm not? There doesn't appear to be anyway of setting the Redirect URI in the call to `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync`

I thought that this would be a 10 minute exercise. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is because the application type for the OAuth Client ID I set up in the Google Developer Console was set to "Web Application". Deleting it and creating a new one with the Application Type set to "other" allows me to authenticate.